# udev - nr_requests on block device not applying on boot but all other rules run correctly

Tags: udev, devices, raid, block-device

### My Rules

```
KERNEL=="sd*",ACTION=="add|change",ATTRS{model}=="PERC_H755N_Front",\
            ATTR{queue/nomerges}="2",\
            ATTR{queue/nr_requests}="1023",\
            ATTR{queue/rotational}="0",\
            ATTR{queue/rq_affinity}="2",\
            ATTR{queue/scheduler}="none",\
            ATTR{queue/add_random}="0",ATTR{queue/max_sectors_kb}="4096"
KERNEL=="sd*",ACTION=="add|change",ATTRS{model}=="Dell Ent NVMe v2",\
            ATTR{queue/nomerges}="2",\
            ATTR{queue/nr_requests}="1023",\
            ATTR{queue/rotational}="0",\
            ATTR{queue/rq_affinity}="2",\
            ATTR{queue/scheduler}="none",\
            ATTR{queue/add_random}="0",ATTR{queue/max_sectors_kb}="4096"
SUBSYSTEM=="block",ACTION=="add|change",KERNEL=="nvme*[0-9]n*[0-9]",ATTRS{model}=="Dell Ent NVMe v2 AGN RI U.2 1.92TB",\
            ATTR{queue/nomerges}="2",\
            ATTR{queue/nr_requests}="1023",\
            ATTR{queue/rotational}="0",\
            ATTR{queue/rq_affinity}="2",\
            ATTR{queue/scheduler}="none",\
            ATTR{queue/add_random}="0",\
            ATTR{queue/max_sectors_kb}="4096"
SUBSYSTEM=="block",ACTION=="add|change",KERNEL=="md*",\
            ATTR{md/sync_speed_max}="2000000",\
            ATTR{md/group_thread_cnt}="64",\
            ATTR{md/stripe_cache_size}="8192",\
            ATTR{queue/nomerges}="2",\
            ATTR{queue/nr_requests}="1023",\
            ATTR{queue/rotational}="0",\
            ATTR{queue/rq_affinity}="2",\
            ATTR{queue/scheduler}="none",\
            ATTR{queue/add_random}="0", ATTR{queue/max_sectors_kb}="4096"
```

### Problem Description

In this case, I'm specifically interested in the one for the PERC at the top. If I run `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger` everything applies just fine. However on reboot, *all* rules apply *except* the one for `nr_requests` and I can't seem to figure out why. A full sequence of my testing is below and you can see that as soon as I manually trigger the rules everything applies correctly. However, on reboot, `nr_requests` is still set incorrectly to 5089. I can't think of anything that makes the property `nr_requests` special in a way that everything else would set but not it.

### Testing

```
[root@r7525 ~]# reboot
Using username "root".
root@192.168.1.60's password:
Activate the web console with: systemctl enable --now cockpit.socket

Register this system with Red Hat Insights: insights-client --register
Create an account or view all your systems at https://red.ht/insights-dashboard
Last login: Fri Sep 16 13:06:28 2022 from 10.8.0.6
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/nr_requests
5089
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/nomerges
2
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational
0
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rq_affinity
2
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
[none] mq-deadline kyber bfq
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/add_random
0
[root@r7525 ~]# udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/nr_requests
1023
[root@r7525 ~]# mv /etc/udev/rules.d/99-my.rules /root
[root@r7525 ~]# reboot
Using username "root".
root@192.168.1.60's password:
Activate the web console with: systemctl enable --now cockpit.socket

Register this system with Red Hat Insights: insights-client --register
Create an account or view all your systems at https://red.ht/insights-dashboard
Last login: Fri Sep 16 13:41:47 2022 from 10.8.0.6
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/nr_requests
256
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/nomerges
2
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rq_affinity
1
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] kyber bfq none
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/add_random
0
[root@r7525 ~]# mv /root/99-my.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/
[root@r7525 ~]# udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/nr_requests
1023
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/nomerges
2
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rq_affinity
2
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
[none] mq-deadline kyber bfq
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/add_random
0
[root@r7525 ~]# reboot
Using username "root".
root@192.168.1.60's password:
Activate the web console with: systemctl enable --now cockpit.socket

Register this system with Red Hat Insights: insights-client --register
Create an account or view all your systems at https://red.ht/insights-dashboard
Last login: Fri Sep 16 13:47:53 2022 from 10.8.0.6
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/nr_requests
5089
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/nomerges
2
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rq_affinity
2
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
[none] mq-deadline kyber bfq
[root@r7525 ~]# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/add_random
0
```